# How to display Google CSE refinements as links rather than tabs?

Tags: css, google-custom-search

If I use the code provided by Google for my CSE the "refinements" are displayed as tabs. I'd like to have them displayed as links down the side rather than as tabs at the top. What is the code for access the "refinements"?

Is this just a CSS issue?

Currently the facets are captured and displayed as links using this code:

```
<?php
            foreach ($result['context']['facets'] as $key) {
                echo "<a class=\"facet-link facet\" href=\"./index.php?q=" . urlencode($_GET['q']). "&amp;facet={$key[0]['label']}\">" . ucfirst($key[0]['anchor']) . "</a> ";
             }
?>
```

Using the default code eliminates the problem I described here in this other question: [How do I access Google CSE refinements via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754741/how-do-i-access-google-cse-refinements-via-api)

Thanks.